# Prerequisites for Stastistics.

Tags: statistics, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm a graduate school student entered this year.

Next semester, I would take mathematical statistics.

I don't think the book used for this class is rigorous [A Course in Mathematical Statistics, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125993153).

But I want to understand Statistics deeply, rigorously.

I hear often Measure Theory is useful for deep understanding of Mathematical Statistics.

So I have studied Real Analysis. G Folland from chapter 1 measure to chapter 3 Radon-Nikodym Theorem and I will study some more.

Could you give me a advice?

Comment: Did you have any prior exposure to statistics?  Why do you study statistics? .

Comment: Absolutely No!. But I have been to seminar about statistics and application. From then I'm interested in statistics.

Comment: Then I'd recommend not to focus on rigor that much in advance. There is a risk of getting lost in technical details and missing the substance. (This applies to various subjects, but here I feel it applies especially.)

Comment: Then, What I do for this class? Professor have not filled out prerequisite blank in Syllabus. Is there any book or advice? @quid I'm sorry that I have bad English.

Comment: I am not in a good position to give specific advice. Naively I'd ask the instructor or, well, just do nothing in advance. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am familiar with this book. Your current background and planned reading in real analysis should
be sufficient for navigating measure theory at the level used in the book.
There is some use of characteristic functions (Fourier
transforms), which require a bit of complex analysis.

This is a second
edition. In the preface to the first edition Roussas mentions linear
algebra and advanced calculus as adequate prerequisites.

This book provides a solid, rigorous and very traditional approach to mathematical statistics.
Do not look for simulation or for any Bayesian approaches.

I suggest you read prefaces to first and second editions (both included) and browse
the first few chapters as you begin the course. That will give you more
information than I can include here, and I suspect nothing to discourage
you.

Comment: Thank you, I read the book when I read  that your adivice. I think Measure theory(Borel measure , Distribution, Product Measure...) is main background. Thank you